# YOCTO how to install 3rd party library(RASPICAM) from github

Tags: build, embedded, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I want to install the raspicam library in the yocto project, but i couldn't find the .bb file anywhere and write the content myself.

https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam

I want to create .bb file for the library in this repo. How can i write the contents of the bb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with below

inherit pkgconfig cmake

RDEPENDS_${PN} = " 
userland 
"

DEPENDS = " 
userland 
"

SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
SRCBRANCH = "master"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/cedricve/raspicam.git;protocol=https;branch=${SRCBRANCH} "

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"